# How to do a foreach in PHP only if there's content in the array?

Tags: php, html

I have this piece of code that retrieves an array from the database and I have to cycle through it to create some html elements, but sometimes the array is empty (when the order that I want to see doesn't have updates). With this syntax how can I avoid the foreach and do nothing in this case? I already made some research and I was able to do this with using fetch() when the page loads with javascript, but I want to do this only using PHP. Thanks in advance.

```
$updates = $order->listUpdates( $os );
<div class="card-body" id="card-body">
    <h6 class="card-title"><?=$res['creation_time'];?> - Abertura da OS</h6>
    <p class="card-text"><?=$res['creation_user'];?> - <?=$res['description'];?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php foreach( $updates as $update ): ?>
    <h6 class="card-title"><?=$update['update_time']?> - Atualização da 
                OS</h6>
    <p class="card-text"><?=$update['update_user']?> - <? 
    =$update['update_content']?></p>
    <hr>
    <?php endforeach;}?>
</div>
```

I know that I have to check if the array is either empty or not, but where do I put the If statement since I doing with this specific syntax  ?

Comment: check if there the array is empty with ```empty($array)``` only then loop through it

Comment: I don't understand the point to this...if there's nothing in the array, the body of the `foreach` will never execute. Why would you bother checking if it's empty first?

Comment: because if the array is empty the foreach throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add an if not empty block where you please for example

```
$updates = $order->listUpdates( $os );
if (!empty($updates)){
foreach( $updates as $update ): ?>
    <h6 class="card-title"><?=$update['update_time']?> - Atualização da 
    OS</h6>
    <p class="card-text"><?=$update['update_user']?> - <? 
    =$update['update_content']?></p>
    <hr>
<?php endforeach;}?>
```

Comment: Code doesn't belong in comments.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment I just replied

Answer (score 0):

I came to this result. It's working but it feels wrong to me.

```
<?php 
if( !empty($updates) ) {
    foreach( $updates as $update ) {
        echo "<h6 class='card- 
        title'>".$update['update_time']."- Atualização da 
        OS</h6>
        <p class='card-text'>".$update['update_user']." - 
        ".$update['update_content']."</p>
        <hr>";
        }
    }           
?>
```